# File system in Vb .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Here is the simple scenario,
I have to move the last modified or recent file from a source folder to the destination folder, anyone can provide sample code for this scenario in vb .net

Comment: Thanks Tim for your clarity, but I am able to find the most recent file in particular directory, the question is after finding that recent file, I need to move the same file to a different directory.

Comment: To move a file, use the [File.Move method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Blockwood, could you please provide me a combined set of code to manipulate the above process(getting the recent file and moving the same file to another location)?